# Umbraco Multinode picker, match list with currentpage

Tags: c#, .net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I need some help with logics how to loop through the items selected in the multinodepicker on all childrens and match them with currentpage type...

Current code:

```
@{
var constructionInfo = Umbraco.Content(2032); //Driftinfo
}

@Articles(constructionInfo)

@helper Articles(IPublishedContent page)
{
    //ToDo: Match contentpicker or tags with currentpage.
    var children = page.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("relaterandeFastigheter") == Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias);
    var relatedArticles = page.Children;

    foreach (var article in children)
    {
            <article>
                <h2>@article.GetPropertyValue("rubrik")</h2>
                @article.GetPropertyValue("text")
            </article>
    }

}
```

So basicly what I tried doing with

```
var children = page.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("relaterandeFastigheter") == Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias);
```

Was to match the property with the Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias. However, I need to somehow match them with the multiple content in the contentpicker as its not single...

Could anyone assist me in finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
var children = page.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("relaterandeFastigheter").Split(',').ToList().Contains(Model.Content.Id.ToString()));
```

That's how I solved it!